# rename x-axis label so that coordinates are show as positive

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I am trying to use 'coord_sf' ( due to the need for the projection) with ggplot2. However, I can't change the labels on the x-axis and remove the `-` sign before the coordinates. I want to label the values in the x-axis as in this plot [image]
(obtained without `coord_sf`).

Sample data and code is below.

```
dts<-structure(list(x = c(-119, -118, -117, -116, -115, -114, -113, 
-112, -111, -110, -109, -108, -107, -106, -105, -104, -103, -102, 
-101, -119, -118, -117, -116, -115, -114, -113, -112, -111, -110, 
-109, -108, -107, -106, -105, -104, -103, -102, -101, -119, -118, 
-117, -116, -115, -114, -113, -112, -111, -110, -109, -108, -107, 
-106, -105, -104, -103, -102, -101, -119, -118, -117, -116, -115, 
-114, -113, -112, -111, -110, -109, -108, -107, -106, -105, -104, 
-103, -102, -101, -119, -118, -117, -116, -115, -114, -113, -112, 
-111, -110, -109, -108, -107, -106, -105, -104, -103, -102, -101, 
-119, -118, -117, -116, -115, -114, -113, -112, -111, -110, -109, 
-108, -107, -106, -105, -104, -103, -102, -101, -119, -118, -117, 
-116, -115, -114, -113, -112, -111, -110, -109, -108, -107, -106, 
-105, -104, -103, -102, -101, -119, -118, -117, -116, -115, -114, 
-113, -112, -111, -110, -109, -108, -107, -106, -105, -104, -103, 
-102, -101), y = c(54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 
54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 
53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 
52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 51, 51, 
51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 
51, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 
54, 54, 54, 54, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 
53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 
52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 
51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51), val = c(3.4, 
3.6, 3.5, 3.4, 3.3, 3.3, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.5, 3.5, 3.1, 3, 
3.4, 3.6, 3.5, 3.1, 3.1, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.7, 3.5, 3.6, 3.5, 3.5, 
3.5, 3.4, 3.3, 3.4, 3.4, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.7, 3.5, 2.9, 3.6, 3.6, 
3.8, 3.8, 3.5, 3.4, 3.4, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 
3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.7, 3.3, 3.5, 3.7, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.6, 3.4, 3.4, 
3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.2, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.4, 3.3, 3.4, -0.7, -0.7, 
-0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, 
-0.6, -0.7, -0.7, -0.6, -0.6, -0.5, -0.7, -0.7, -0.8, -0.7, -0.7, 
-0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, 
-0.7, -0.6, -0.5, -0.8, -0.8, -0.8, -0.8, -0.8, -0.8, -0.8, -0.8, 
-0.8, -0.8, -0.8, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.6, -0.6, 
-0.8, -0.8, -0.8, -0.8, -0.8, -0.8, -0.8, -0.8, -0.8, -0.8, -0.8, 
-0.8, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.6, -0.6)), row.names = c(NA, 
-152L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Code. This code creates the plot but the labels in the x-axis are negative and I cannot change it to make positive. ANy help would be appreciated.

```
plt<-ggplot(dts,aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_tile(aes(fill=val),alpha=1)+
  coord_sf(datum = st_crs(3978))+ #must keep this projection ( or how can i use EPSG::3978 with coord_map ?)
  xlab("Longitude (°W)")+
  ylab("Latitude (°N)")
  # scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-120,-100,2),
  #                    labels = seq(120,100,-2),
  #                    expand = c(0, 0))
plt
```

Comment: Does `scale_x_continuous(labels = function(x) abs(x)) +` work?

Comment: I was just fixing my comment, @JonSpring. Shorter: `+ scale_x_continuous(labels=abs)`.

Comment: Solution by @r2evans worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
plt<-ggplot(dts,aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_tile(aes(fill=val),alpha=1)+
  coord_sf(datum = st_crs(3978))+ 
  xlab("Longitude (°W)")+
  ylab("Latitude (°N)") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-120,-100,2),
                    labels = abs(seq(120,100,-2)))
plt
```